# I want to measure the distance with smart phone (in range 10-20 cm)

Tags: android, image-processing, bluetooth, accelerometer

I have 3 solutions in my mind.

1. Measure by 2 smart phones using bluetooth. I know that this method may not be accurate because of the environment around the phone, but I just want to measure in the short range (about 10-20 cm) and I assume that nothing blocks between these 2 phones so is it possible?
2. Using the accelerometer.
3. Image processing. Assume that I want to know the distance between some object and my phone. I have seen from some webboard that I need to know the object's size so I can calculate for the distance. Is it possible to do something like this? And is it possible that no reference object is needed, just capture anything and know the distance?

Actually I want the measurement method for using with the flexibility test, extending arms forward as far as possible. I just want to know how far I can extend my arms and hands forward. Is there any suggestion to help finding the distance. Thanks for all your helps.

Comment: 1. **No**: Bluetooth is **not a sensor**. 2. **No**: not the right sensor (how do you relate an **acceleration** to a distance?). 3 **No**: you **do need a reference**. The measurements will be **inaccurate** even with a reference. `I suggest you buy an inexpensive bulk Arduino nano and a cheap Bluetooth module. Apply some sensors and couple the custom wearable device with your phone to read the returned values.`

Answer (score 0):

To some extent the autofocus of the camera could do, if you can readout the focus setting.

The image processing approach is certainly viable. Distance from a single view is not possible if you don't know the object size.

My recommendation: create a sufficiently rigid measurement target made of two black circles surrounded by a large white ring. Measure the distance between centers (let us call it the *base*) and circle diameters, in millimeters.

When you capture an image, use thresholding and blob analysis to find the circles. Measure the base and the diameters, in pixels (it can be helpful to check the ratio of the two diameters and diameter/base ratio to detect false positives).

Alternatively, use a single large black circle on a white background and use its diameter as the base.

Lastly, calibrate your system: placing the target at various distances, determine the base. Plot the (base, distance) points. They should align on a smooth curve, close to a straight line.

You will use interpolation or fitting between the data points to convert a given base to actual distance.

UPDATE:

For minimalistic programming, a QR reader can help you: if your platform has a QR reader that returns the location of the code (corners or centers of the finder patterns), you can use a QR code of known size as the target. For the base as above, you can use a diagonal of the code.